# How python interpreter giving this output?

Tags: python

when I print this it giving me this output I don't understand How?

```
>>> print(1,000,000)
1 0 0
```

Comment: It's syntactically equivalent to `print(1, 0, 0)`.

Comment: With the commas, there are 3 values that `print` needs to print. `1` and two `000`s. `000` is just `0`. Hence the output.

Comment: try `print(1_000_000)`

Comment: Try printing like a string e.g `print('1,000,000')`

Answer (score 3):

You are printing 3 different values. Its the same as this:

```
print('Hi', 'hello world', 'bye bye')
```

And 000 is interpreted as 0, example:

```
print(000000000)
```